# Structure sorted by values instead of keys

Tags: scala

In Scala, I need to create a structure which contains the following:

- a `Bitset` - represents some cells which are occupied or not
- an `Int` - the last cell occupied
- an `Int` - the cost of this occupation

Because an element is uniquely identified by the combination of the `Bitset` representing occupied cells and the `Int` representing the last cell occupied, I tried using the following:

```
var tm = TreeMap.empty[Path, Int]
```

Where `Path` is:

```
case class Path(occupied: BitSet, last: Int)
```

However, the issue is that I want to sort the elements in the `TreeMap` by their cost(so by their Value). This is apparently not possible for `TreeMap`.

So can I have a structure where I sort the elements by Value rather than Key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you look for a sorted-set then:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.BitSet
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet

case class Path(occupied: BitSet, last: Int, cost: Int)

implicit val pathOrd = Ordering.by((p: Path) => p.cost)

SortedSet.empty[Path]
```

Assuming that `cost` is a field of `Path`. If the cost is calculated from the `Path`, you could also define:

```
case class Path(occupied: BitSet, last: Int) {
  def cost: Int = ???
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I would like to uniquely identify a `Path` element by `occupied` and `last` and not by `cost`. Can I do that using a `SortedSet`?

Comment: @octavian Yes, if you define `cost` as a method (see code above) or as a second constructor parameter list, such as `case class Path(occupied: BitSet, last: Int)(val cost: Int)`. Identity for case classes only takes the parameters of the first list into account.

Comment: `case class Path(occupied: BitSet, last: Int)(val cost: Int)` doesn't work for me. I get an error when I try to instantiate the class: 
`error: missing arguments for constructor Path in class Path
            new Path(newBs, newLast)`

Comment: Well you need to provide all arguments then, like `Path(BitSet(1, 2, 3), 4)(5)`. If you want the cost to be calculated from the other two arguments, use the `def cost` version above.